# How can i retrive data from nested object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

```
I stored some object in localStorage,  how i can access all of data using loop.I want to work with long data. How can i find the
```

solution.
** I have some data in object like as: **
From Local storage:
Basic:{
Question:{
Question1:{
Id:1,
Question: "what is php?",
},
Question2:{
Id:1,
Question: "what is js?",
},
},
}′
Medium:{
Question:{
Question1:{
Id:1,
Question: "what is php?",
},
Question2:{
Id:1,
Question: "what is js?",
},
},
}
Advanced:{
Question:{
Question1:{
Id:1,
Question: "what is php?",
},
Question2:{
Id:1,
Question: "what is js?",
},
},
}
Html:
`<div class="process"> <li> Basic </li> <li> Medium </li> <li> Advanced </li>`
**I tried to access  like**:
`Object obj = new Object(); $('.process li').each(function (){ obj = JSON.parse(localStorage[$(this).text()]; obj[$(this).text()]['question'].each(function(){`
How can i print all id & question
`}); });`
I tried lots of way. But don't get any best solution. Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off restructuring your data so that it's an object with basic/medium properties that are arrays of objects. Iterating over those array is then pretty simple.

Here's a jQuery example.

```js
const data = {
  basic: [{
      id: 1,
      question: 'what is php?'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: "what is js?"
    }
  ],
  medium: [{
      id: 3,
      question: 'what is narwhal?'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: "what is goat?"
    }
  ]
};

const list = $('ul');
const keys = Object.keys(data);

for (const key of keys) {
  
  const type = $(`<li>${key}</li>`);
  const sublist = $('<ul></ul>');
  
  for (const q of data[key]) {
    const item = `<li>${q.id}: ${q.question}</li>`;
    sublist.append(item);
    type.append(sublist);
  }
  
  list.append(type);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

The native JS is very similar.

```js
const data={basic:[{id:1,question:"what is php?"},{id:2,question:"what is js?"}],medium:[{id:3,question:"what is narwhal?"},{id:4,question:"what is goat?"}]};

const list = document.querySelector('ul');

const keys = Object.keys(data);

for (const key of keys) {
  
  const type = document.createElement('li');
  const sublist = document.createElement('ul');
  type.textContent = key;
  
  for (const q of data[key]) {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = `${q.id}: ${q.question}`;
    sublist.appendChild(item);
    type.appendChild(sublist);
  }
  
  list.appendChild(type);

}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```